# Chrome PDF print preview error in servlet

Tags: java, google-chrome, pdf, crystal-reports

I have a problem with print preview in google-chrome when i am trying to print pdf generated from servlet. Error appears only in default pdf plugin, it works with Adobe pdf plugin. Code for pdf output in servlet:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","public");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"crreport.pdf\""); 

        /*if (byteArrayInputStream != null){
            byteArray = new byte[1024];
            while((bytesRead = byteArrayInputStream.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
                response.getOutputStream().write(byteArray, 0, bytesRead);  
            }
        }else {
            throw new Exception("byteArrayInputStream is null!");
        }*/

        if (byteArrayInputStream != null){
            byteArray = new byte[byteArrayInputStream.available()];
            byteArrayInputStream.read(byteArray);
            response.setContentLength(byteArray.length);

            response.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);

        }else {
            throw new Exception("byteArrayInputStream is null!");
        }

        System.out.println("End");
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
```

In Chrome errorLog when i try to preview generated pdf:
*Ignoring plugin with unexpected MIME type application/pdf (expected application/x-google-chrome-print-preview-pdf)*

But preview works if i save this pdf with default save button in right-down corner of chrome page and open it from local machine.

I tried googleit but in a large number of questions about chrome pdf plugin cant find any usefull information. Any suggestions how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what was the main problem in my case. I've tried to generate pdf report using crystal report for eclipse plugin. It seems that generated byteArrayInputStream  by CR4E is somehow corrupted in such way that it doesn't work only in Chrome default pdf plugin. It can be workaround with iText library. PDF  assembled with use of iText on base of CR4E byteArrayInputStream can be normally previewed and printed.

Answer (score 0):

The use of available as file length is wrong; by definition it is the part that can be read immediately without blocking (= waiting for the next part to be read). It might often give the length. The output stream of the response should not be closed.

```
    if (byteArrayInputStream == null){
        throw new Exception("byteArrayInputStream is null!");
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, byteArrayOS);

    byteArray = byteArrayOS.toByteArray();
    response.setContentLength(byteArray.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);

    System.out.println("End");
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    //response.getOutputStream().close();
```

To what caused the error: maybe available behaved differently on different resource usage of both plugins.

Comment: I corrected errors in code which you marked. Thanks for your comment, but it didn't solve main problem with chrome print preview.